# Create a dataset that makes 0/1 flag any time a record is present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I've got a table that is designed to have 1 row per member per product usage per month. There are three products. Most people only use one product, but some us a combination of the others.
Ideally I'd like to have a result set that looks like:

[image: dataset-example]

However I'm only able to get it to show the same as it is now, but with 1's and 0's. So if a person used all three products, there would be three rows with 1's rather than one row with 3 1's.

Here's how the code looks right now:

```
WITH
   dist_visit_typ_cte(visit_month, person_id, product_type) as
(select distinct visit_month, person_id, product_type
from product_transaction_table), 

visit_count_cte (visit_month, person_id, prod_a_usage, prod_b_usage, prod_c_usage) as
(select distinct visit_month
    ,CASE WHEN product_type = 'A' then 1, else 0 end as prod_a_usage
    ,CASE WHEN product_type = 'B' then 1, else 0 end as prod_b_usage
    ,CASE WHEN product_type = 'C' then 1, else 0 end as prod_c_usage
from dist_visit_typ_cte
group by
      visit_month
    ,CASE WHEN product_type = 'A' then 1, else 0
    ,CASE WHEN product_type = 'B' then 1, else 0
    ,CASE WHEN product_type = 'C' then 1, else 0
```

It's on an older version of SQL-Server (pre 2016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation. The logic you want would look like:

```
select visit_month, person_id,
    max(case when product_type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) prod_a_usage,
    max(case when product_type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) prod_b_usage,
    max(case when product_type = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) prod_c_usage
from dist_visit_typ_cte
group by visit_month, person_id
```